# Workflow: Show initiation form after creating new item?

Tags: workflow, infopath, visual-studio, initiation-form

I want to start my Visual Studio 2010 sequential workflow automatically after adding a a new form (or any document for that matter) to a form library.

This works flawlessly as long as I don't have an initiation form. As soon as I have an initiation form, the workflow fails. When I start it manually, the initiation form is displayed and the workflow goes about doing its things.

Is there any way to call the workflow initiation form of a specific workflow after new item generation (in particular an InfoPath form)?

So basically I want this:

1. User enters information on InfoPath form
2. Submits said form to a library
3. Workflow X is started and user is asked for initiation data

Yes, I could put the initiation data also on the first InfoPath form, from step 1 - but this is not the solution I am looking for.

The error I am receiving is `There is an error in the XML document (0,0)` right after trying to Deserialize the `workflowProperties.InitiationData`. Why this error? Because I did not enter any InitiationData! I would do so on the Initiation Form, which wasn't shown after creating a new item. Hence the Initiation Form XML is null, hence the error.

Comment: is the workflow giving you any failed error messages?

Comment: I added error information, but your "answer" should be a comment. The error I am receiving is simply related to workflowProperties.InitiationData being empty - of course it is empty because the initiation form was not shown to me. When manually starting the workflow on any existing item, the initiation form is shwon.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of putting the initiation data into an InfoPath form is the only approach that will work here, even though it's not the solution you're looking for. Office clients don't have integration with Visual Studio workflows.

Any reason why you can't use InfoPath here? Microsoft have a [complete walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms548723.aspx) on how to do it.